# Does SAS proc logistic perform variable selection?

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

I am trying to fit a multinomial logistic regression model. I have four outcomes. I also need to do a variable selection. I have about 15 variables. I know that in the model statement, if I use `link=glogit` then it will perform multinomial logistic regression. However, is there a way to do variable selection also?

Answer (score 0):

`proc logistic` has a few different variable selection methods that can be specified in the `model` statement. See Table 60.8 [Effect Selection Options](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/67523/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_syntax22.htm) in the documentation. Many of these options and syntax are shared with other procedures, such as `proc glmselect` and `proc reg`.

They provide a [Stepwise Selection](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/67523/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_examples01.htm) example that shows one way to use automatic variable selection.

```
proc logistic data=Remission outest=betas covout;
   model remiss(event='1')=cell smear infil li blast temp
            / selection=stepwise
              slentry=0.3
              slstay=0.35
              details
              lackfit;
   output out=pred p=phat lower=lcl upper=ucl
      predprob=(individual crossvalidate);
run;
```

Comment: This has only two responses. I have more than 2 responses that's why I need to fit multinomial logistic regression.

Comment: Variable selection options will still work regardless if it's multinomial or binomial.